# why react hooks form with custom input first removes error and then we can type?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-hook-form

when the form field shows error message and I want to try to type, when it reaches the point to clear the error first it clear the error and then I am able to type.
please check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-firefly-86lfg?file=/src/App.js), click inside a field and then click outside it to produce the error and now try to type something for example (1111), the problem is that you have to press 1 six times to achieve 1111, I couldn't find how to solve it.

any help please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a section under FAQ: https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Whyisfirstkeystrokeisnotworking which explains which this happens. Long story short, you are mixing uncontrolled with controlled input.

You have the following option

Register:

1. `<TextInput ref={register} name="test" defaultValue="test" /> // without value`

Controller:

2. `<Controller as={TextInput} name="test" />`

https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

Which also contains example in the link above.